# I want to Implement Google Authentication to my Flutter Windows Application

Tags: flutter, windows, authentication

I want to Implement Google Authentication to my Flutter Windows Application, I Tried google_sigin plug but it does'nt support windows application.

How to achieve google sign in to my flutter windows application?

Do we have any documentation?

I tried with url_launcher for browser based login, but in local while creating Create a HTTP server listener i am getting error.